# How to compose a buildout.cfg for zc.buildout with SVN-based sub projects

Tags: python, build, build-automation

I want to make an zc.buildout configuration for production use.  In my case, I have two sub-projects from two separate SVN repositories.  I want to deploy these into the same web site.  Basically, these are two sub-sites that will go into the same web server.  I can manually put this together on my PC, but I'd like to use buildout.  How do I do this?  It strikes me that I need to first get the latest version of the two sites from SVN (put them where?)  Next, run the buildout script on each of the sub-projects???  Next, run the buildout script in the master project???  Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your luck with [`mr.developer`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer), it can check out and update your svn projects during buildout automatically.

Something like:

```
[buildout]
extensions = mr.developer
auto-checkout =
  foo
  bar
parts = baaz

[sources]
foo = svn https://svn.foo.com/trunk/
bar = svn https://svn.bar.org/trunk/

[baaz]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = 
  foo
  bar
```

Note, this is not a complete working example, just a general buildout layout.